# Calculation yielding zero in c++

Tags: c++

I'm working on this code where I calculate how long it takes a person to get to a specific planet from the Earth. My problem is that for time variable I keep getting zero. As a result, the other variables hours and years also give zero. What is wrong with it?

I know it is not casting because they are already double.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char choice = 0;
    double weight = 0;
    double speed = 0;
    double time = 0;
    double newWeight;
    double distance = 0;
    double gravity = 0;
    double newtoSun = 0;
    double earthtoSun = 93;
    double days = 0;
    double years = 0;
    string planet;

    cout << "welcome" << endl;
    cout << "menu" << endl;
    cout << "a) mercury" << endl;
    cout << "b)Venus" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice >= 'a' && choice <= 'd')
    {
        cout << "enter weight" << endl;
        cin >> weight;

        cout << "What speed u want?" << endl;
        cin >> speed;

        if (choice == 'a')
        {
            newtoSun = 36;
            gravity = 0.27;
            planet = "Mercury";
        }
        else if (choice == 'b')
        {
            newtoSun = 67;
            gravity = 0.86;
            planet = "Venus";
        }
        else if (choice == 'c')
        {
            newtoSun = 93;
            gravity = 1;
            planet = "Earth";
        }
        else if (choice == 'd')
        {
            newtoSun = 141;
            gravity = 0.37;
            planet = "Mars";
        }

        newWeight = weight * gravity;
        time = distance / speed;
        distance = abs(earthtoSun - newtoSun);
        days = time / 24;
        years = days / 365;

        cout << "INTERPLANETARY TRAVEL: Earth to " << choice << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Your weight on " << planet << fixed << setw(5)
                << setprecision(2) << newWeight << endl;
        cout << distance << endl;
        cout << speed << endl;
        cout << "Your travel time to " << planet << ":" << endl;
        cout << "In Hours: " << setw(2) << time << "hours" << endl;
        cout << "In Days : " << setw(2) << days << "days" << endl;
        cout << "In Years  : " << setw(2) << years << "years" << endl << endl;

    }

    else if (choice == 'q')
    {
        cout << "You quit" << endl;
    }

    else
        cout << "You have entered an invalid selection" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
time = distance / speed;
distance = abs(earthtoSun - newtoSun);
```

These statements are backwards.